# Make objects of an image the closest to each other

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I don't have much experience with PIL and I've got these images edited from a stack of microscopy image cells, each one is in a mask of an image size 30x30. I've been struggling to put these cells in a black background as closest as possible to each other without overlapping.

My code is the following:

```
def spread_circles(circles, rad, iterations,step):
    radsqr = rad**2
    for i in range(iterations):
        for ix,c in enumerate(circles):
            vecs = c-circles
            dists = np.sum((vecs)**2,axis=1)
            if len(dists)>0:
                push = (vecs[dists<radsqr,:].T*dists[dists<radsqr]).T
                push = np.sum(push,axis=0)
                pushmag = np.sum(push*push)**0.5
                if pushmag>0:
                    push = push/pushmag*step
                    circles[ix]+=push
    return circles



def gen_image(sample,n_iter, height=850, width = 850, max_shape=30, num_circles=150):
    circles = np.random.uniform(low=max_shape,high=height-max_shape,size=(num_circles,2))   
    circles = spread_circles(circles, max_shape, n_iter, 1).astype(int)
    img = Image.new(mode='F',size=(height,width),color=0).convert('RGBA')
    final1 = Image.new("RGBA", size=(height,width))
    final1.paste(img, (0,0), img)
    for n,c in enumerate(circles):
        foreground = sample[n]       
        final1.paste(foreground, (c[0],c[1]), foreground)     
    return final1
```

But it's hard to avoid overlapping if I do few iterations, and if I Increase they'd be too much sparsed, like this:

[image]

What I want it's something similar like inside the red circles that I drew :

[image]

I need them closer as they can get, almost like tiles. How can I do that?

Comment: Cool question! I am unclear as to how they got in such a mess in the first place? Do you have them available as separate images (each less than 30x30) somehow that you could share them like that.. e.g. a Zip archive of separate images in Dropbox, Google drive? Or should I cut them out of the first of your 2 images?

Comment: Also, my initial idea is that **OpenCV** or **skimage** may be a better choice of tool. What are the constraints please?

Comment: I don't reject a good way with skimage or opencv, in fact I started with openCv then I struggled to get transparency of the image and then I found an easier way with PIL. You have the images in the following link. No major constraints just want the objects near to each other and in a black image background as I showed with the red circles.     https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13iAJ4qFjOVt1Q4eCq7J3YFV0AQYpDkB-?usp=sharing

Comment: How about something that starts packing along these lines? http://thesetchells.com/StackOverflow/cells.png Are the cells allowed to touch in the final image? Is it allowed to rotate them? Have you looked at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing

Comment: That cells.png image seems good. There's no problem to rotate them. Just don't overlap,   I don't know if that happens by touching but if it meant to be near each other to the max it's allowed and the perfect thing. I haven't seen that circle packing but I'm exploring now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have started thinking about this and have got a couple of strategies implemented. Anyone else fancying some fun is more than welcome to borrow, steal, appropriate or hack any chunks of my code that they can use! I'll probably play some more tomorrow.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import math

def checkCoverage(im):
   """Determines percentage of image that is cells rather than background"""
   N = np.count_nonzero(im)
   return N * 100 / im.size


def loadImages():
   """Load all cell images in current directory into list of trimmed Numpy arrays"""
   images = []
   for filename in glob('*.png'):
      # Open and convert to greyscale
      im = Image.open(filename).convert('L')
      # Trim to bounding box
      im = im.crop(im.getbbox())
      images.append(np.array(im))
   return images

def Strategy1():
   """Get largest image and pad all images to that size - at least it will tesselate perfectly"""
   images = loadImages()
   N = len(images)
   # Find height of tallest image and width of widest image
   maxh = max(im.shape[0] for im in images)
   maxw = max(im.shape[1] for im in images)
   # Determine how many images we will pack across and down the output image - could be improved
   Nx = int(math.sqrt(N))+1
   Ny = int(N/Nx)+1
   print(f'Padding {N} images each to height:{maxh} x width:{maxw}')
   # Create output image
   res = Image.new('L', (Nx*maxw,Ny*maxh), color=0)
   # Pack all images from list onto regular grid
   x, y = 0, 0
   for im in images:
      this = Image.fromarray(im)
      h, w = im.shape
      # Pack this image into top-left of its grid-cell, unless
      # a) in first row, in which case pack to bottom
      # b) in first col, in which case pack to right
      thisx = x*maxw
      thisy = y*maxh
      if y==0:
         thisy += maxh - h
      if x==0:
         thisx += maxw - w
      res.paste(this, (thisx,thisy))
      x += 1
      if x==Nx:
         x  = 0
         y += 1

   # Trim extraneous black edges
   res = res.crop(res.getbbox())
   # Save as JPEG so we don't find it as a PNG in next strategy
   res.save('strategy1.jpg')
   cov = checkCoverage(np.array(res))
   print(f'Strategy1 coverage: {cov}')


def Strategy2():
   """Rotate all images to portrait (tall rather than wide) and order by height so we tend to stack equal height images side-by-side"""
   tmp = loadImages()
   # Recreate list with all images in portrait format, i.e. tall
   portrait = []
   for im in tmp:
      if im.shape[0] >= im.shape[1]:
         # Already portrait, add as-is
         portrait.append(im)
      else:
         # Landscape, so rotate
         portrait.append(np.rot90(im))
   images = sorted(portrait, key=lambda x: x.shape[0], reverse=True)
   N = len(images)
   maxh, maxw = 31, 31
   # Determine how many images we will pack across and down the output image
   Nx = int(math.sqrt(N))+1
   Ny = int(N/Nx)+1
   print(f'Packing images by height')
   # Create output image
   resw, resh = Nx*maxw, Ny*maxh
   res = Image.new('L', (resw,resh), color=0)
   # Pack all from list 
   xpos, ypos = 0, 0
   # Pack first row L->R, second row R->L and alternate
   packToRight = True
   for im in images:
      thisw, thish = im.shape
      this = Image.fromarray(im)
      if packToRight:
         if xpos+thisw < resw:
            # If it fits to the right, pack it there
            res.paste(this,(xpos,ypos))
            xpos += thisw
         else:
            # Else start a new row, pack at right end and continue packing to left
            packToRight = False
            res.paste(this,(resw-thisw,ypos))
            ypos = res.getbbox()[3]
      else:
         if xpos>thisw:
            # If it fits to the left, pack it there
            res.paste(this,(xpos-thisw,ypos))
            xpos -= thisw
         else:
            # Else start a new row, pack at left end and continue packing to right
            ypos = res.getbbox()[3]
            packToRight = True
            res.paste(this,(0,ypos))

   # Trim any black edges
   res = res.crop(res.getbbox())
   # Save as JPEG so we don't find it as a PNG in next strategy
   res.save('strategy2.jpg')
   cov = checkCoverage(np.array(res))
   print(f'Strategy2 coverage: {cov}')

Strategy1()
Strategy2()
```

---

Strategy1 gives this at 42% coverage:

[image]

Strategy2 gives this at 64% coverage:

[image]

Comment: I do like strategy 2, very good. Even though it's sorted by size I can adapt a little bit to mix a little with smaller and bigger cells,  making small images/boxes and then aggregate.